# Getting (#100) Unknown fields: username in Spring Social Facebook

Tags: spring, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I am trying to implement FB login and retrieve friend list by using [this](http://paxcel.net/blog/spring-social-fetch-users-friend-list-from-facebook/) link.

Now as given in dependencies I am using following one in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency> 

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Now I am getting proper accessCode by providing login information and trying to get the friendList by using following code :

```
Facebook fb = new FacebookTemplate(accessToken);
List<FacebookProfile> friends = fb.friendOperations().getFriendProfiles();
```

At above code I am getting following exception :

```
org.springframework.social.UncategorizedApiException: (#100) Unknown fields: username.
    org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.FacebookErrorHandler.handleUncategorizedError(FacebookErrorHandler.java:158)
```

Tried googling it and came to know that the username fields has been no longer required, but still don't have clear idea how to resolve this in my case.

Answer (score 7):

On April 30th, Facebook released version 2.0 of their API which removed the "username" field. Spring Social Facebook 1.0.3 (which is the version you're using) targets version 1.0 of Facebook's API. Therefore when it tries to fetch the "username" field, you get that error.

Even Spring Social Facebook 1.1.1 (the latest GA release of Spring Social Facebook) will give you that error because it was release just before Facebook announced version 2.0 of their API.

Per Facebook's rules, any application registered *after* April 30, 2014 is required to target version 2.0 of the API. (Apps registered before April 30th can choose which version they want to use.) This means that any application registered after 4/30 may get errors such as the ones you get when using Spring Social Facebook 1.0.x or 1.1.x.

There is good news, however: Spring Social Facebook 2.0.0.M1 is completely updated to target Facebook's v2.0 API. I encourage you to give it a shot and see if it resolves your problem. Note that you will also need to use Spring Social Core 1.1.0, as Spring Social Facebook 2.0.0.M1 is not compatible with Spring Social Core 1.0.2.RELEASE.

Comment: Does the problem continuous between Spring Social Core 1.1.2.RELEASE and Spring Social Facebook 2.0.1.RELEASE. ?